# Weird character conversion, need help clarifying

Tags: java, unicode, jsoup, character, jxl

So i am writing a program that takes data extracted to an excel sheet from a web page and then prints it to a text note. However, a weird problem that I have encountered is that from the excel sheet to the text note, a character has changed. the - has turned into a ? . My solution was to iterate through the word and when it gets to the ? and change it to a - . I've tried using unicodes that I've found online and done a

```
.replace("(question mark unicode) ", " - ")
```

to no avail. Does anyone have any idea as to why it is doing that? and can you confirm the unicodes for ? and - . So if the word was "Leo‑III 1.3" it is now "Leo?III 1.3" Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is a result of character set encoding issues, and can occur at many places in the data pipeline.

It could actually be in the printing of the string, and the string itself is valid.

To find out what the actual character value is, try running this code to print the Unicode escape for all non-ASCII characters found in the string:

```
public static void printNonAscii(String s) {
    TreeSet<Character> nonAscii = new TreeSet<>();
    for (char ch : s.replaceAll("[\r\n\\x20-\\x7E]", "").toCharArray())
        nonAscii.add(ch);
    for (char ch : nonAscii)
        System.out.printf("\\u%04X  %s%n", (int) ch, ch);
}
```

*Test (source in UTF-8)*

```
printNonAscii("Foo ? \uFFFD ç ñ © ¼");
```

*Output*

```
\u00A9  ©
\u00BC  ¼
\u00E7  ç
\u00F1  ñ
\uFFFD  �
```

Comment: what do you mean by Test(source in UTF-8)? Also it spit back /u2011. What does that mean?

Comment: Also, I tried a method mentioned by another user so String newreheader = reheader.replaceAll("\u2011","-") and it worked so thank you

Comment: @Beat. Unicode has many "hyphen" characters, e.g. the `‑` (['NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' (U+2011)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)) looks the same as the normal `-` (['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)), but tells word-processing tools like Word to not break the line after the hyphen. There are many other hyphen characters in Unicode, e.g. `‐` (['HYPHEN' (U+2010)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm)), `–` (['EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)), ...

Answer (score 1):

replace in java takes character as the first argument and replaces all occurrences by the 2nd argument.

you can rather use this:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\?", "-");
```

the replaceAll takes 1st argument as a regex and replaces all matches by 2nd argument.

**Note: \ help escape ?**

**also, be sure to store the result in a new String variable as strings are immutable.**

Comment: i tried .replace("\?", "-") and it says its not acceptable

Comment: @Beat. `replaceAll()` and not `replace()`

Comment: @Beat. i have edited my answer to use 2 \ i.e "\\?" and not "\?". Sorry bout that! try "\\?" and it should work

Comment: doesn't work for whatever reason.  String newreheader = reheader.replaceAll("\\?", "-"); still does nothing.

Comment: @Beat. I tried it in my IDE again and it worked for me! can you paste a Console output after replaceAll()? because it should have worked!
also for teh sake of testing try pastin this in a java file as it worked for me:
`String s2 =  "this i s??new?hh";`
`String s3 = s2.replaceAll("\\?", "-");`
`System.out.println(s3);`

Comment: Another user brought up it might be an encoding issue and I think their right because this isn't regular text, it's pulled from a webpage and then put into excel sheet and then written to a text file. It changes from the excel file to the text file. Your idea probably would work if It wasn't so messed up. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Beat. sorry and Hope you find the right solution !

Comment: Another use provided a solution to get the right encoding. I gave that user the solved because they were able to help with the encoding thing but if I could mark multiple people I would give it to you to for your help and idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Beat. no worries. really appreciate your gesture !

Answer (score 1):

According to Java docs, the String class's `replace` method takes either a primitive `char`,  or object implementing `CharSequence` (like String)  as its parameters.

If you want to convert Leo?III 1.3 to Leo-III 1.3, use:

`.replace("?", "-")`

Comment: I tried that before to no avail, sorry for not mentioning it earlier. Thought I did.